# Java random math equation generating random answers

Tags: java, math, random, java.util.scanner, equation

I am coding a problem where it will be x (+ or - or *) y =z and it will generate 4 possible answers for the user which has 1 good and 3 wrong answers. I made most of the code but I do not get how I make the same formula used again for Reponse() because right now when I execute the code, Equation() makes his own one and Reponse() does another different formula. Also I need to know how I can make sure that the code works by adding a system that will show a formula like 5 +5 = ? 
and the code will show 4 answers which has one good one.

here's the code:

```
    public class Equation {

    int x, y, z;


    public Equation() {
        Random r = new Random();
        x = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
        y = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
        z = 0;
        char operator = '?';

        switch (r.nextInt(3)) {
            case 0:
                operator = '+';
                z = x + y;
                break;
            case 1:
                operator = '-';
                z = x - y;
                ;
                break;
            case 2:
                operator = '*';
                z = x * y;
                ;
                break;
            default:
                operator = '?';
        }

        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(operator);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(y);
        System.out.print(" = ");
        System.out.println(z);

    }

}
```

and for Reponse() the one that generates the answers:

```
    public class Reponse {
    Equation equ = new Equation();
    int a, b, c, d;
    char operator = '?';

    public Reponse() {
        Random r = new Random();
        switch (r.nextInt(4)) {

            case 0:
                a = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                break;

            case 1:
                b = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                break;

            case 2:
                c = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                break;
            case 3:
                d = equ.z;
                break;
            default:
                operator = '?';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted a considerable amount of code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: @JoeC I said that Equation generates the formula but so does Reponse() instead of generating 4 answers choices in a console asking which is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are initializing the new instance of `Equation` class inside your `Response` class.

```
Equation equ = new Equation();
```

Whenever you'll do something like,

```
Response r = new Response();
```

A new instance of `Equation` will be instantiated.

What you should be doing is as follows,

1. Change the `Response` class as follows:

   ```
   public class Response {
       int a, b, c, d;
       char operator = '?';

       public Response(Equation equ) {
           Random r = new Random();
           switch (r.nextInt(4)) {

               case 0:
                   a = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                   break;

               case 1:
                   b = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                   break;

               case 2:
                   c = r.nextInt(2 * equ.z);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   d = equ.z;
                   break;
               default:
                   operator = '?';
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** I have deleted the instance of `Equation` from the class and am passing it to the constructor.

2. Create a new instance of `Equation`,

   ```
   Equation equ = new Equation();
   ```
3. Create a new instance of `Response` by passing above `Equation` instance,

   ```
   Response r = new Response(equ);
   ```

Now, you can create multiple instances of `Response` class using the same instance of the `Equation` class that you instantiated.